magento2 custom price layred navigation
I have use below code but multi-select filter not working when i have before filter proper ranges show after filter ranges removed
<?php

namespace Bliss\CustomPriceRange\Search\Dynamic\Algorithm;

use Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\DataProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\EntityStorage;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Request\BucketInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\OptionsInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\Algorithm\AlgorithmInterface;

/**
 * Class PredefineRange
 *
 * Implements the AlgorithmInterface to provide predefined price ranges for dynamic search.
 */
class PredefineRange implements AlgorithmInterface
{
    /**
     * Constant for the predefined range calculation.
    */
    const RANGE_CALCULATION_PREDEFINE_RANGE = 'predefine_range';

    /**
     * Constant for the 250 under range calculation.
    */
    const RANGE_UNDER_250 = 250;

    /**
     * Array of predefined price ranges.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    const RANGES = [
        [0, 250],    // £250 and under
        [250, 500],  // £250 - £500
        [500, 750],  // £500 - £750
        [750, 1000], // £750 - £1000
        [1000, 2500],// £1000 - £2500
        [2500, 5000],// £2500 - £5000
        [5000, 10000], // £5000 - £10000
        [10000, null], // £10000+
    ];

    /**
     * @var DataProviderInterface Data provider for fetching data.
     */
    private $dataProvider;

    /**
     * @var RequestInterface HTTP request instance.
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * @var OptionsInterface Options for the search adapter.
     */
    private $options;

    /**
     * PredefineRange constructor.
     *
     * @param DataProviderInterface $dataProvider Data provider for fetching data.
     * @param RequestInterface $request HTTP request instance.
     * @param OptionsInterface $options Options for the search adapter.
     */
    public function __construct(
        DataProviderInterface $dataProvider,
        RequestInterface $request,
        OptionsInterface $options
    ) {
        $this->dataProvider = $dataProvider;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    /**
     * Get items for the specified bucket and dimensions.
     *
     * @param BucketInterface $bucket The bucket for which to get items.
     * @param array $dimensions Dimensions for the search.
     * @param EntityStorage $entityStorage Storage for entities.
     * 
     * @return array An array of items with counts and range values.
     */
    public function getItems(BucketInterface $bucket, array $dimensions, EntityStorage $entityStorage) 
    {
        $entityCount = count($entityStorage->getSource());
        if ($entityCount < 1) {
            return [];
        }

        $data = [];
        $interval = $this->dataProvider->getInterval($bucket, $dimensions, $entityStorage);

        foreach (self::RANGES as $index => $range) {
            $rangeResult = $interval->load($entityCount, null, $range[0], $range[1]);

            $count = count($rangeResult);
            
            if($count > 0){
                $data[] = [
                'count' => $count,
                'from' => $range[0],
                'to' => $range[1],
            ];
            }
            
        }

        return $data;
    }
}


can any one face this problem?
